# Run lua file other than main in replit

Tags: lua, replit

I'm trying to run a lua file other than main on replit.com, and I'm not sure how to do that. I know in java you just type "java name_of_file" into the terminal but typing "lua name_of_file) doesn't work.

Here is a screenshot of what I'm trying to do:

[image: Screenshot]

Here is my code on replit, so you can try running it: https://replit.com/join/kxisutsa-suzm10

Comment: Inside repl try `dofile("activity.lua")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently in console, use shell instead and use `lua activity.lua` to run the activity.lua file.